# PHP – Change static variable in method

Tags: php, variables, static

I need to change static variable in method. The code looks something like this:

```
function get_something()
{
    static $cache = array();
    if (!$cache) {
        $cache = $this->compute_cache();
    }
    return $cache;
}
```

I can get a copy of value.

```
$reflection = new ReflectionMethod($object, 'get_something');
$vars = $reflection->getStaticVariables();
```

Is there a way to change the value in method?

P.S.
I cannot change the code of that method.

Comment: No, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot change the static variable in a method. They are private to the method.

However if you define the $cache as a static variable in the class, and not the method, you will be able to access it.

e.g.

```
class A {
  static $cache;
}

$object = new A();
$object::$cache = 33;
echo $object::$cache;
```

Comment: Then can you create a class that extends the behaviour of $object so that $cache is accessible?